# Do I need the DVD to reformat 2011 MacBook Pro with OS X Yosemite

Tags: macbook-pro, recovery, install, internet-recovery

I have a MacBook Pro from early 2011 which was shipped to me with a DVD that I could use to reformat the machine, which I do not have with me at the moment.  I have upgraded to OS X Yosemite though, and have reformatted the newer Retina MacBooks which used an Internet connection to download the OS.

Since I do not have the disc handy, will I be able to do this later reformatting on my older MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MacBook Pro (early 2011) was updated with [Macbook Pro EFI Firmware Update 2.3](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1450?locale=en_US) then you will be able to use [OS X Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202313) and not need the DVD that shipped with your Mac.  Also have a look at: [OS X: About OS X Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)

Comment: hmm I wonder how I can verify I have the needed firmware?

Comment: @erikvold, What's the output from Terminal of the following command? `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep 'ROM'`